# Metodo dentro de arquivos sem classe. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Pessoal me deparei com um codigo dentro de um arquivo flutter (dart) que me deixou com algumas duvidas,
é um arquivo dart sem classe declarada apenas com uma metodo. Tentei olhar na documentação a respeito mas acho que não soube pesquisar.
Queria saber qual o possível prejuízo de usar isso.

### arquivo.dart

```
String getErrorString(String code){
  switch (code) {
    case 'ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD':
      return 'Sua senha é muito fraca.';
    case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
      return 'Seu e-mail é inválido.';
    case 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE':
      return 'E-mail já está sendo utilizado em outra conta.';
    case 'ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL':
      return 'Seu e-mail é inválido.';
    case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
      return 'Sua senha está incorreta.';
    case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
      return 'Não há usuário com este e-mail.';
    case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
      return 'Este usuário foi desabilitado.';
    case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
      return 'Muitas solicitações. Tente novamente mais tarde.';
    case 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED':
      return 'Operação não permitida.';
    default:
      return 'Um erro indefinido ocorreu.';
  }
}
```

Comment: Dart é uma linguagem orientada a objetos e em Dart funções também são objeto da linguagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há qualquer problema com esta função e é algo comum em existir. As funções não precisam estar associadas a classes, na verdade, se uma 'função' está dentro de uma classe como você mencionou, ela é na verdade denominada método (conceito de orientação a objetos).

A própria função `main()` da linguagem não está associada a classe alguma e é declarada livremente em um arquivo. Assim como o `print()`, entre várias outras.

```dart
int minhaFuncao() => 42;

class MeuObjeto {
  int meuMetodo() => 42;
}

void main() {
  print(minhaFuncao()); // 42
  print(MeuObjeto().meuMetodo()); // 42
}
```

#### Funções em Dart são objetos

As funções, assim como tudo em Dart, também são objetos do tipo `Function`. Como prova disso, basta pegar uma função qualquer e ver que você pode chamar métodos e atributos que estão presentes na classe `Object`:

```dart
int minhaFuncao() => 42;

void main() {
  print(minhaFuncao.toString()); // Closure: () => int from Function 'minhaFuncao': static.
  print(minhaFuncao.runtimeType); // () => int
}
```

Por conta disso, podem ser atribuídas a variáveis ou passadas por parâmetro para outras funções/métodos:

```dart
void main() {
  final lista = [4, 2];
  lista.forEach(print); // 4 // 2
}
```

Repare como a função `print` é passada por parâmetro para o método `forEach` da lista. Ele pode receber qualquer função que tenha a assinatura necessária:

```dart
void forEach(void f(E element)) {
  for (E element in this) f(element);
}
```

#### Classes como funções

Outra possibilidade, é fazer com que uma determinada classe seja tratada como uma função. As chamadas [Callable Classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes). Basta implementar o método `call()` dentro dela:

```dart
class Resposta {
  void call() => print(42);
}

final respostaSobreAVidaUniversoETudoMais = Resposta();

void main() {
  respostaSobreAVidaUniversoETudoMais(); // 42
}
```